# how to add attribute name in summernote click to edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I want to add element attribute name in summernote click to edit

html :

```
<button id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="edit()" type="button">Edit 1</button>
<button id="save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()" type="button">Save 2</button>
<div class="click2edit">click2edit</div>
```

javascript:

```
var edit = function() {
  $('.click2edit').summernote({focus: true});
};

var save = function() {
  var makrup = $('.click2edit').summernote('code');
  $('.click2edit').summernote('destroy');
};
```

doc :
http://summernote.org/examples/#click-to-edit

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: nothing error, I just want to add attribute name in summernote editor, for example <textarea name="content" class="note-codable"></textarea>

Comment: I understand what you're looking for, check my answer and try it.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39952607/6608101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var edit = function() { 
  $('.click2edit').summernote({focus: true});
  $('.note-editor').find('textarea').attr('name','mytextarea');
};
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. Just find the text area add the name attribute.Hope it work.

```
var edit = function() {
    $('.click2edit').summernote({focus: true});
    $('.note-editor.note-frame.panel.panel-default').find('textarea').attr('name','mytextarea');
};
```

Comment: thanks rupesh, I modified like this, and its worked. var edit = function() { 
            $('.click2edit').summernote({focus: true}); 
            $('.note-editor').find('textarea').attr('name','mytextarea'); 
        };

Comment: If it worked for you .Then you may correct my ans and increase my repo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need anything fancy here.

Use `attr()` on `summernote selector`

```
$('.summernote').attr('name', 'content');
```

Here, I assume that `$('.summernote')` is selector of editor applied.

Example, shows how to get instance of editor

```
$("#id").on("summernote.init", function(e, layoutInfo) {
    // get $editor element 
    var $editor = layoutInfo.editor();

    // add id attribute in $editor element 
    $editor.attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + "-of-example");
}).summernote(
    // summernote options.. 
);
```